# How to set the default title of Anchor Tag in Wordpress for all post

Tags: html, css, wordpress, anchor, title

I have an issue. By default on hover on blog post thumbnail, i am getting the title description but i dont want any title description on hover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idtKs.png)

Comment: Hi ,Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code

Comment: if you can edit the code, then remove the title tag from image tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script in footer.php

```
        <script>

        jQuery('a["title"]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        </script>
```

**OR**

you need to remove the title tag from all layout
from below the path

`gridlove\template-parts\cover\layout-1.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\cover\layout-2.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\cover\layout-3.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\cover\layout-4.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\layouts\content-a.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\layouts\content-b.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\layouts\content-c.php`

`gridlove\template-parts\layouts\content-d.php`

```
<?php if( $fimg = gridlove_get_featured_image('cover') ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>" class="gridlove-cover">
        <?php echo $fimg; ?>
        <span class="gridlove-hidden-overlay"></span>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: glad to help you :)